# Ordering by date in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following column in a csv file. How can I arrange the entire dataframe from oldest to newest. I currently have the following code:  po_dataset.sort_values("date",ascending=True)
But I am not getting the proper order.

```
Date
12/12/2020
14/11/2020
28/11/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the values in the `date` column to `datetime` objects, like this:

```py
po_dataset["date"] = pd.to_datetime(po_dataset["date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can see a complete list of the various `%`-formats [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Then sort them:

```
po_dataset.sort_values("date", ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date (strings) to datetime type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

then you can sort values. If you don't want to change your data type (which is not recommended), then convert the dates to a temporary series, and reindex:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).sort_values().index]
```

Output:

```
         Date
1  14/11/2020
2  28/11/2020
0  12/12/2020
```